# Problemas al crear un apartado de Perfil

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes tengo un problema ya que trato de crear un perfil segun el usuario que esta logueado pero me aparece error, este es mi código de php con mi formulario

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        include("connection.php");
        
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$id'";   
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
        
        if ($mostrar) {
        ?>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <div class="perfil-usuario-body">
        <div class="perfil-usuario-bio">
            <h3 class="titulo"><?php echo $mostrar['usuario'] ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="perfil-usuario-footer">
            <ul class="lista-datos">
                <li><i class="icono fas fa-map-signs"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['matricula'] ?></td></li>
                <li><i class="icono fa fa-calendar"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['fn'] ?></td></li>
                <li><i class="icono fas fa-briefcase"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['area'] ?></td></li>
                <li><i class="icono fa fa-envelope"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['correo'] ?></td></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="lista-datos">
                <a href="home.html">
                    <li><i class="icono fa fa-home"></i> Inicio</li>
                </a>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <li><i class="icono fa fa-sign-out"></i> Cerrar Sesion</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
        }
?>
</section>
```

mas que cuando reviso los resultados me aparece este error en mi navegador

Warning
: Undefined variable $id in
C:\xampp\htdocs\A\perfil.php
on line
30

Warning
: Undefined variable $id in
C:\xampp\htdocs\A

Comment: Estas asignando la variable `$id` a una variable de sesión?. Invierte esto `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;` así `$id = $_SESSION['id'];`. Intenta y comenta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo mucho y me soluciono el error que me mandaba ahora no me aparecen los datos pero no me marca error alguno

Comment: Revisa la información que tienes en cada una de las variables con `echo($sql);` y `var_dump($mostrar);die;` por ejemplo. De este modo te darás cuenta en dónde está el error.